# Prove Infimum and Supremum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I am having this set:

$$ X= (-1.1) =  \{x \in \mathbb{R} \ \ |-1<x<1 \}  $$

**How can I prove that $\inf X= -1$ and $\sup X=1$ ?**
(I think there is no maximum and no minimum in X?)

Comment: Use the definition of sup and inf. What have you got so far?

Comment: @SimonS I know the definitions, but I am having problems to write it down correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supremum is the least real number which greater than (or equal to) all elements of $X$. It doesn't have to be in $X$. So you should see that $1$ is greater than all elements of $X$, but for all reals less than $1$ there's a greater one in $X$, so there are no lower bounds and the supremum is $1$.

The infimum is analogous.

---

More formally: Let us show $1$ is the supremum of $(0,1)$:

- For all $x\in(0,1)$ it's true that $x\le1$, so it's an upper bound.
- For all $u<1$, set $x=\frac12$ if $u<0$ so that $x\in(0,1)$ and $u<x$, so it can't be an upper bound. Else $u\ge0$ and set $x=\frac{u+1}2$, this is clearly bigger than $u$ and less than $1$, so $u$ also can't be an upper bound.

This proves $1$ is a supremum. Infimum is done analogically.

Comment: Thanks for explanations, but my problem is not to find the infimum/supremum (I know the definitions), I am having a problem to write it down correctly.

Comment: @user3433232 Better?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a hint to help you prove that supremum is $1$. The infimum case can be handled similarly.

**Characterisation of Supremum:** A number '$a$' is said to be supremum of set $S$ if it is an upper bound and for every $\epsilon>0$, you can always find an element '$x$'in $S$ such that $1-\epsilon<x$.

Clearly, $1$ is an upper bound and $x=(1-\frac{\epsilon}{2})\in S$ such that $1-\epsilon<x$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is true. You can base your proof on the fact that:

if $ A \in \mathbb{R} $ is a boundary of $ X \subset \mathbb{R} $ and we can find a sequence $ X \ni a_n  $ s.t. $ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = A $, then it is the infinum or supremum